# Change value according to UTC time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to go about changing value of a float according to time?

For example. We have:

```
public float usdValue = 1f;
```

How to make it so value of USD changes randomly according to UTC time? Like + or - between -20% to +75% of its value during time? While its value changes every 1-5 minutes?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you want something to respond to elapsed time intervals, you need something that _measures_ elapsed time intervals, like a `Timer` instance or a `Stopwatch` instance.

Comment: What do you mean by: *"changes randomly according to UTC time*"? If the value changes according to something, is it really considered "random"? Do you mean you want to update a variable to a random value within a specified range at a specific frequency?

Comment: Are you trying to randomly change the value of usdValue to within -20% to +75% at timed intervals? e.g. at 1 minute the value is changed to 1.2f. At 2 minutes the value is change to 1.3f etc...

Answer (score 1):

This will randomly generate an interval between 1-5 minutes (60-300 seconds) and value modifier between 20-75%. While the elapsed time since resetting is less than the interval, the value remains unchanged. Once the interval time is passed, it will will recalculate.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class USDValueRandomizer : MonoBehaviour {

    public float usdValue = 1;
    public float ModifiedUSDValue = 1;

    public int MinIntervalTimeInSeconds = 60;
    public int MaxIntervalTimeInSeconds = 300;

    public float MinValueModifier = 0.2f;
    public float MaxValueModifier = 0.75f;

    private DateTime IntervalStart;
    private int IntervalTimeInSeconds;
    private float ValueModifier;

    private void Start()
    {
        RecalculateValue();   
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        TimeSpan elapsedTime = DateTime.UtcNow - IntervalStart;

        if (elapsedTime.Seconds >= IntervalTimeInSeconds)
            RecalculateValue();

        ModifiedUSDValue = usdValue * ValueModifier;
    }

    private void RecalculateValue()
    {
        IntervalStart = DateTime.UtcNow;
        IntervalTimeInSeconds = Mathf.RoundToInt(UnityEngine.Random.Range(MinIntervalTimeInSeconds, MaxIntervalTimeInSeconds));
        ValueModifier = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0.2f, 0.75f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw this answer out there - it works in C#, but it's not related at all to Unity3d (I don't know anything about Unity3d), so maybe there is some other modifications needed.

If I understand you correctly, you want to change the value of a `decimal` (currency should always be stored in a `decimal`) to a random value that is between `-20%` and `+76%` of it's current value, and you want this to happen at a random interval, between `1` and `5` minutes.

If that's correct, one way to do this would be to use a `System.Threading.Timer`:

```
public static decimal UsdValue = 1;
private static readonly Random Rnd = new Random();
private static readonly Timer Timer = new Timer(TimerCallback);

private static void TimerCallback(object obj)
{
    // Choose a random percentage between -20% and 76%
    var pctChange = Rnd.Next(-20, 76) / 100M;
    var plusSign = pctChange >= 0 ? "+" : "";

    // Update our value and log it to console
    UsdValue += UsdValue * pctChange;
    Console.WriteLine(
        $"{DateTime.Now}: USD value is now: {UsdValue:c} ({plusSign}{pctChange:P0})");

    // Choose a random value between 1 and 5 minutes (in milliseconds)
    var waitTime = Rnd.Next(60000, 300001);
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}: Next update in {waitTime / 60000} minutes.");
    Console.WriteLine(new string('-', Console.WindowWidth));

    // Change the timer interval to the new value
    Timer.Change(waitTime, Timeout.Infinite);
}

private static void Main()
{
    // Start timer right away
    Timer.Change(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.Zero);
    Console.ReadKey(); // To keep console window active
}
```

**Output**

Note that for the sample output, I changed the value to be between 1 and 15 seconds because I didn't want to wait that long!

```
// Set the next interval to a random value between 1 and 15 seconds (in milliseconds)
var waitTime = Rnd.Next(1000, 15000);
Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}: Next update in {waitTime / 1000} seconds.");
```

[image: Example Console Output]

Comment: Good solution, but Unity miiight have issues with System.Timer because threading is a finicky mess.